# Why does the CreateProcess() function not work?

Tags: c++, powershell, winapi, process

I am trying to call the CreateProcess function to execute some powershell command. The function doesnt return any errors but it doesnt execute the command (there is no file created after running the app). Here is the code.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));


// Start the child process. 
if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    const_cast<LPTSTR>(TEXT("powershell.exe -command  echo Hello > D:\\out.txt")),        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )
{
    std::cout << ("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
}

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

// Close process and thread handles. 
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

Comment: What does [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess) say?

Comment: Why suspicious casting?

Comment: Regarding the command line argument: "The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string)."

Comment: @molbdnilo that was the problem. Changing the function to CreateProcessA fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Or, you could make a writeable copy of the string - `TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT("powershell.exe -command  echo Hello > D:\\out.txt");` - and pass that, which would work in either case.

Comment: Calling CreateProcessA is jot the fix. Passing a writeable character array is the answer.